# A Groovy script that wraps pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have several components(code projects with their own Bitbucket repositories) and each of them has a Jenkinsfile as follows:

```
properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: "", description: "List of components", name: 'componentsToUpdate'),
                        string(defaultValue: "refs%2Fheads%2Fproject%2Fintegration", description: "BuildInfo CommitID", name: 'commitId'),
                        string(defaultValue: "", description: "Tag to release, e.g. 1.1.0-integration", name: 'releaseTag'),
                        string(defaultValue: "", description: "Forked buildInfo repo. Be aware right commit ID!!!", name: 'fork')]),
                        [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '7', numToKeepStr: '5']],
                        disableConcurrentBuilds()])

@Library('jenkins-shared-stages')

import mergePipeline
import releasePipeline
import ripplePipeline
import componentPipeline


def branchName = env.BRANCH_NAME
def rewriteDependencies = ""
def returnValue = null
def forkedRepo = params.fork
def buildInfoCommitId = params.commitId
def tagToRelease = params.releaseTag
println "buildInfoCommitId: " + buildInfoCommitId
if(params.componentsToUpdate) {
    rewriteDependencies = params.componentsToUpdate
}

if (branchName == "project/integration") {
    mergePipeline {
    }
} else if (branchName == 'master') {
    releasePipeline {
        releaseTag = tagToRelease
    }
} else {
    returnValue = componentPipeline {
        componentsToUpdate = rewriteDependencies
        commitId = buildInfoCommitId
        runOnForkedRepo = forkedRepo
    }

    rewriteDependencies = rewriteDependencies.isEmpty() ? returnValue : rewriteDependencies + "," + returnValue
    println "WHAT is rewriteDependencies? " + rewriteDependencies
    println "The return value: " + returnValue
    ripplePipeline {
        commitId = buildInfoCommitId
        componentName = returnValue
        runOnForkedRepo = forkedRepo
        componentsToUpdate = rewriteDependencies
    }
}
```

To keep this file clean, I wish to move the above code to a groovy script(**placed in the same directory(vars) as the other pipeline scripts**), which in turn will be invoked from the Jenkinsfile.

I tried something like below:
Jenkinsfile

```
properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: "", description: "List of components", name: 'componentsToUpdate'),
                        string(defaultValue: "refs%2Fheads%2Fproject%2Fintegration", description: "BuildInfo CommitID", name: 'commitId'),
                        string(defaultValue: "", description: "Tag to release, e.g. 1.1.0-integration", name: 'releaseTag'),
                        string(defaultValue: "", description: "Forked buildInfo repo. Be aware right commit ID!!!", name: 'fork')]),
                        [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '7', numToKeepStr: '5']],
                        disableConcurrentBuilds()])

@Library('jenkins-shared-stages@integration/CICD-959-wrapper-pipeline-for-the-jenkinsfile') _

import pipelineScriptWrapper

pipelineScriptWrapper.trigger(params)
```

While I knew it was wrong to not refer to the argument reference type, I couldn't figure out whether to use a Map or java Properties or something else:
pipelineScriptWrapper.groovy

```
import mergePipeline
import releasePipeline
import ripplePipeline
import componentPipeline
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

def trigger(params) {

    //Figure out a way to make this work in a Groovy script
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())

   // Assuming we have multibranch pipeline job or defined branch name in the env
    def branchName = env.BRANCH_NAME
// There is a bug in the Jenkins it will pass a string "null" as a gradle build parameter instead of NULL object if there is
// empty parameter has been passed!!!
    def rewriteDependencies = ""
    def returnValue = null
    def forkedRepo = params.fork
    def buildInfoCommitId = params.commitId
    def tagToRelease = params.releaseTag

    def notifyHandler = new se.NotifyHandler()

        try {
            logger.info("The buildInfoCommitId is {}", buildInfoCommitId)
            logger.info("Branch name: {}", branchName)

            println "buildInfoCommitId:  "+buildInfoCommitId
            println"Branch name: "+branchName

            if (params.componentsToUpdate) {
                rewriteDependencies = params.componentsToUpdate
            }

    // keep the same integration pipeline for the master branch for now
            if (branchName == "project/integration") {
                logger.info("Invoking mergePipeline")
                println "Invoking mergePipeline"
                mergePipeline {
                }
            } else if (branchName == 'master') {
                logger.info("Invoking releasePipeline")
                println "Invoking releasePipeline"
                releasePipeline {
                    releaseTag = tagToRelease
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("Invoking componentPipeline")
                println "Invoking componentPipeline"

                returnValue = componentPipeline {
                    componentsToUpdate = rewriteDependencies
                    commitId = buildInfoCommitId
                    runOnForkedRepo = forkedRepo
                }
                logger.info("Component pipeline has returned {}", returnValue)
                println "Component pipeline has returned"+returnValue

                // We need to provide new version of the component to the Ripple builds
                rewriteDependencies = rewriteDependencies.isEmpty() ? returnValue : rewriteDependencies + "," + returnValue
                logger.info("rewriteDependencies: {}", rewriteDependencies)
                println "The return value: " + returnValue
                ripplePipeline {
                    commitId = buildInfoCommitId
                    componentName = returnValue
                    runOnForkedRepo = forkedRepo
                    componentsToUpdate = rewriteDependencies
                }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            def build_status = "Exception ${err.message} in build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
            logger.error(build_status,err)
            notifyHandler.NotifyFail(build_status, PIPELINE_NAME)

            throw err
        }
}
```

As expected, it failed to even compile. How do I proceed?
Note: I am new to both Jenkins pipelines and Groovy/DSL :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the way you import your script, scripts in `vars` should automatically import.
See: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables

You want to use a parameter of type `Map` in Groovy, which is also consistent with the way you read those `params` inside the `trigger` method.

What I am also wondering is, how is this supposed to execute?
I mean how are the parameters supposed to come into the `Jenkinsfile` when it runs?
Are you possibly looking for interactive input?
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#-input-%20wait%20for%20interactive%20input